# Google Calendar Api (Events: watch) not working for other CalendarIds

Tags: google-calendar-api, webhooks

I've been trying to use the fantastic Google Calendar API but I encountered a problem:

I've created a channel that is going to remind me when a resource in events change.

The problem is that the channel only notifies me when something change only in the primary calendarId. For example if someone adds a new event in a different calendarId I will not be notified.

Isn't it a little weird? Is there something I am missing from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a google calendar expert, but trying to look into the API explains that [list API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) will give the list of events for that specific calendarID and [watch API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch) will provide the details.

As your question says

> if someone adds a new event in a different calendarId

You have to pass the new CalendarID in the request to make it work for the different calendar.

List API:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events

Watch API:

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/watch

Comment: I just realized that in Watch API there is a field for calendarId. I didn't see that. Thank you for saving some time for me my friend. I was assuming that it would work for every calendarId